# Is It Possible To Light The End Portal With A Flint And Steel

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In minecraft, is  it possible to light the end portal, without killing the E-dragon or exploding a end crystal, with only a flint and steel(and maybe some armor JIC)?

Comment: This question can easily be answered using Google, the wiki or simply trying it. Please do a little bit of research, that saves you and us time.

Answer (score 1):

No to use the end portal the only current way (as of the 1.13 aquatic update) is to put eye of ender around on all of the end portals whereas the nether can be used with flint and steel

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible (at least without modding tools).

The portal leading to The End requires Eyes of Ender in order to light. The portal leading back to the overworld only spawns after the Ender Dragon is killed. Neither interact in any way with Flint & Steel. That kind of mechanic only applies to Nether Portals.

If you *really* want to have an End Portal without actually killing the Ender Dragon, you can use a map editor to manually create the End Portal tiles that lead back to the Overworld.